# Opening a new Activity when clicking a menu item button is not working

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

So I have 2 activities and in the first one I have a menu item that once clicked should open the second activity. The changing part works but it's not changing what it is supposed to, in the second activity which I activate with this :

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, EditView.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
```

in the first activity onOptionsItemSelected, and I click a button from the menu, in this second activity I have a diferent layout and I do this setContentView(R.layout.second); to change the layout I have a functional xml file because I tried it in another project, in the manifest file I have this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ro.merca.ionel"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".FileList"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".EditView"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />

    </application>


</manifest>
```

the problem is that when I click the option from the menu it loads a simple layout without all the things I put in second.xml... I don't know that the problem is...

```
public class EditView extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    final TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
    final TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

    setContentView(tv);

}   
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add(1,1,1,"Salveaza Nota").setIcon(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
    menu.add(1,2,2,"Anuleaza Modificari").setIcon(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
    menu.add(1,3,3,"Sterge Nota").setIcon(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
    menu.add(1,4,4,"Share").setIcon(android.R.drawable.btn_default);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case 1 : 
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, EditView.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case 2 :
            break;
        case 3 :
            break;
        case 4 : 
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Nume" />
    <EditText  
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Text" />
    <EditText
        android:id = "@+id/text"
        android:inputType="text|textMultiLine"
        android:minLines="5"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 

        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You need to post your code for the second activity (editview).

Comment: And also put the xml of the second layout.

Comment: Please post the code and xml for the second activity and layout resp.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? The activity is not starting, or the activity IS starting, but the layout doesn't display correctly?

Comment: the activity is starting but the layout is differrent

Comment: Is the layout completely different than planned, or close to the intended layout?

Comment: Like @Adborn said, you're calling onCreate twice, so the second one will overwrite the first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `setContentView` twice in `onCreate()`. Remove the second one and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I am bit confused over here. If you are just moving from 1st activity to 2nd without passing any values then what's the use of using `getIntent()` etc?

Write simply this much, and you will land on your desired activity:

```
public class EditView extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second);
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    final TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
    final TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
  }   
}
```